# How to resolve missing "content-length" header while pushing an image to a self hosted docker registry?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I have self-hosted a docker registry by following [this](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/). But when I try to push any images it fails with a missing `content-length` error.

```
missing content-length header for request: https://registry.filthyweebs.in/v2/test-image/blobs/sha256:b52eb23a552e2c2a580f2adc60e6b3d2c06e23c90323f3abfd4f9ffc3aa464f6
```

I have created the following `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'

services:
  registry:
    restart: always
    image: registry:2
    ports:
    - "7244:5000"
    environment:
      REGISTRY_AUTH: htpasswd
      REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM: Registry
      REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH: /auth/registry.password
      REGISTRY_STORAGE_FILESYSTEM_ROOTDIRECTORY: /data
      REGISTRY_VALIDATION_DISABLED: true
      REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE: /certs/fullchain.pem
      REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY: /certs/privkey.pem
    volumes:
      - ./auth:/auth
      - ./data:/data
      - ./certs:/certs
```

Upon checking the log I found some errors but I still have no clue why they are there

```
time="2023-08-13T07:11:08.651744609Z" level=error msg="response completed with error" auth.user.name=admin err.code=unknown err.detail="invalid byte in chunk length" err.message="unknown error" go.version=go1.19.9 http.request.host=registry.filthyweebs.in http.request.id=14e4c98d-848b-4398-b0a7-b8d57ec794e0 http.request.method=PATCH http.request.remoteaddr=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx http.request.uri="/v2/test-image/blobs/uploads/a0fa5af8-211d-445c-902b-5c5d7aadaac4?_state=zkuo-95XSKgz212Hf2nt3ZpOuX-qqzL2ROwU8hyCkVl7Ik5hbWUiOiJ0ZXN0LWltYWdlIiwiVVVJRCI6ImEwZmE1YWY4LTIxMWQtNDQ1Yy05MDJiLTVjNWQ3YWFkYWFjNCIsIk9mZnNldCI6MCwiU3RhcnRlZEF0IjoiMjAyMy0wOC0xM1QwNzoxMTowOC4wODkzNzU4NjFaIn0%3D" http.request.useragent="docker/20.10.25+dfsg1 go/go1.20.7 git-commit/5df983c kernel/6.3.0-kali1-amd64 os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/20.10.25+dfsg1 \(linux\))" http.response.contenttype="application/json; charset=utf-8" http.response.duration=15.292544ms http.response.status=500 http.response.written=98 vars.name=test-image vars.uuid=a0fa5af8-211d-445c-902b-5c5d7aadaac4
```

Is there some step or configuration that I am missing? I have tried setting it up twice and both times it is throwing the same error.

The server is hosted on Debian's bookworm distro and the client is using Kali Linux (rolling) with all the latest updates.

Comment: What client are you using to push the image?

Comment: Docker version 20.10.25+dfsg1, build b82b9f3`